Fleet-server elastic search log shows too many colons in address
I'm using elastic search and trying to configure fleet-server , when i enrolled with token it successfully enrolled but when i check the log in fleet management I'm getting this error:

[elastic_agent][error] 2024-05-16T03:53:24Z - message: Application: fleet-server--7.17.21[84a8c876-fd6c-482a-ac30-76fb3b289af8]:
State changed to FAILED: Error - listen tcp: address http://13.202.33.84:8220: too many colons in address - type: 'ERROR' - sub_type: 'FAILED'

The command I used to enroll:
sudo elastic-agent enroll 
     --fleet-server-es=http://xx.xxx.xx.xx:9200   
     --fleet-server-service-token=xxxxxx   
     --fleet-server-policy=xxxxxx   
     --fleet-server-insecure-http   
     --fleet-server-host=localhost   
     --fleet-server-port=8220


Can you try to add \\ after the end of the each line ?
